# How to get a single s3 file creation event

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have several amazon s3 buckets that different clients upload files to, typically using sftp. Because different clients access the buckets in different ways, I can't exactly anticipate how they will upload the files. I want to be notified when a new file arrives, so I have the buckets write to an SNS topic when any s3 object creation even is triggered. However, for some clients, this results in 3 different events for each file creation:

1. An `ObjectCreated:Put` event with filesize 0
2. An `ObjectCreated:Copy` event with the full filesize
3. An `ObjectCreated:CompleteMultiPartUpload`, also with the full filesize.

I have a lambda function listening to this event, and I want it to only act once per file. Is there any to distinguish these duplicate events?

I don't want to have the s3 bucket only write about `Copy` or `CompleteMultiPartUploads`, because I worry that some clients will only trigger one of these (unless there is some guarantee that one of these triggers for every single s3 file creation, but I haven't seen that in the docs anywhere).

I don't really want to log received files in a database with my lambda, because that would make it challenging to detect when a client legitimately re-uploads a file with the same name.

I'm sure my lambda is working properly and these are distinct events, not retries

Answer (score 1):

You should only get one notification for a file. But in any case, for s3 file event triggers, you can use the option `All object create events` option. This will send one event per file.

Comment: Nice answer!  Could you go into a bit more detail about how to use that option?

Comment: It is when using the `All object create events` option that I receive multiple events

Comment: I have not seen this happen in my experience using s3 file event triggers. Either, an object is uploaded to s3 using `PutObject` or if it is big enough a `MultiPartUpload`. Can you provide an example file or method to re-create this? Can you also share the event json if possible for duplicates?